# CRC calculation takes too much time

Tags: java, android, crc

On an Android app I am developing I can recognize a file through its CRC32, MD5 or SHA1 (I have xml file with a list of these).

I read that CRC32 is the faster to be calculated, so I decided to use this one, but to calculate CRC32 of a 4MB file it takes about 3 minutes, and I need to do it on more and even bigger files in a shorter time. Is this a regular time for a device with dual 1.5GHz CPU and 1GB RAM? If not, could it be due to heap limitations? Will improve if I compile a native C to calculate CRC through shell with `Process.exec` ?

**EDIT Code:**
I added a BufferedInputStream and now it takes about 7 seconds. But 1 minute for 35MB file.

```
InputStream fi = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));

int gByte = 0;
CRC32 gCRC = new CRC32();
while ((gByte = fi.read()) != -1) {
    gCRC.update(gByte);
}
fi.close();
```

Comment: May be the IO is too slow

Comment: Please add your checksum code, as it could came to bad crypto API use...

Comment: How do you caculate crc32?

Comment: My thirty year old microcomputer with a 2MHz 8-bit 6502 processor can calculate CRC32s at about the same rate.  For a modern device it is ridiculously slow.

Comment: Post some code. Almost certainly you are spending the time in I/O, not the CRC calculation.

Comment: I've added the code I' m using

Comment: Exactly as suspected. Add a BufferedInputStream, or read into a byte[] array instead of a single byte at a time, and your problem will disappear.

Comment: @EJP like this? `InputStream fi = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));`

Comment: Don't waste time. There's only one possible way to do it. Try it.

Comment: @EJP this reduced time to about 7 seconds. Is it an average time or can it still be improved?

Comment: CRC32 cannot only be used for data integrity, it's malleable

Comment: @UkuLoskit it's enough for what I want to achieve :) By the way, considering 7 seconds is the average calculation time, how much this time will increase if I'll rely on sha1 or md5?

Comment: @UkuLoskit Data integrity is what CRCs are *for.* A CRC32 has a very high probability of detecting transmission errors. I have no idea what 'malleable' is supposed to mean in this context.

Comment: i meant "can only be used for", you cannot use it in cases where suspect that someone has maliciously changed the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
byte[] buf = new byte[1024*64];
while ((gByte = fi.read(buf)) > 0) {
    gCRC.update(buf, 0, gByte);
}
fi.close();
```

java nio might even help a bit more for large files.

Answer (score 2):

A decent software CRC-32 implementation should be able to process over 1 GB per second on modern processors.  I get 1.2 GB/s on my 2 GHz i7.

You need to feed big chunks to the CRC algorithm.  Do *not* feed it one byte at a time.

By the way, I get 18 GB/s on my 2 GHz i7 using the hardware crc32 instruction.

md5 and sha1 both are about 0.35 GB/s.  sha256 is about 0.18 GB/s.